# jquery hover won't work

Tags: jquery, hover

I am trying to get the Jquery hover function to work or the mouseenter/mouseleave functions to work. I want to add and remove classes on an image and div when another div is hovered.

I created a jFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/ljk999/w5bmxyp4/

So when the div:

```
<div id="enhancedtextwidget-17" class="feature feat1 col-xs-6 col-sm-3 widget_text enhanced-text-widget">
```

is hovered I want to remove the "start" class from the img and the "feat-overlay" div and add a class of "hover-start" to them.

Can anyone help me figure out how to do that?

Thank you.

Comment: Please post your code here, not just a fiddle link.

Comment: When I hover over the circle the highlight moves from the top left to the top right. What is supposed to happen instead?

Answer (score 0):

The specific functionality that you asked for is outlined below.  I tried to drive what I thought you were trying to accomplish so it may not be exactly what you wanted but I think it is close.  There seemed to be a clash of the `.toggleClass()` instantaneous behavior and the CSS code timing so I put it in a JavaScript `setTimeout()` method to avoid the issue.

You can un-comment the `//$menuImg.toggleClass('start');` to observe the behavior when the `start` class is removed.

```
var $menuShell = $('div#features > div'), $menuImg = $menuShell.find('img'), $featOverDiv = $menuShell.find('div.feat-overlay'), $sisterDivs = $menuShell.siblings();

var yesAnimate, noAnimate;

function startTimer() {
    yesAnimate = setTimeout(function() {
        //$menuImg.toggleClass('start');
        $featOverDiv.toggleClass('start');
    }, 600);
}

function leaveTimer() {
    noAnimate = setTimeout(function() {
        //$menuImg.toggleClass('start');
        $featOverDiv.toggleClass('start');
    }, 0);
}

$menuShell.not($sisterDivs).on('mouseenter', function() {
    startTimer();
    $menuImg.toggleClass('start-hover');
    $featOverDiv.toggleClass('start-hover');
});

$menuShell.not($sisterDivs).on('mouseleave', function() {
    leaveTimer();
    $menuImg.toggleClass('start-hover');
    $featOverDiv.toggleClass('start-hover');
});
```

[Fiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/dixalex/u8fkdbkv/3/)

Comment: Hi Alexander, thank you for your help. What I am actually trying to accomplish is to have the start animation that is currently working but when you hover over the circle it rotates 90 degress and when you hover back out it goes back to normal. I want to stop the starting animation when you do the hover out and add the animation that goes back to 0 degrees when hovering out. I thought if I removed the start class on hover and added a new class on hover, then I could have the different hover out behaviour. I have the hover out animation happening, but the beginning animation is still happening.